# no output while displaying the values of arraylist

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist

I have written a c# code which displays the values stored in arraylist.

```
static void Main()
        {

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(@"C:\\shreyas\\NX_Temp\\NX_Temp\\000048_A\\CompareReport3D.xml");


            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("*");
            List<XmlNode> returnedmatchNode=TraverseXml(nodeList);
             for (int iIndex = 0; iIndex < returnedmatchNode.Count; iIndex++)
             {

                 Console.WriteLine("values" +returnedmatchNode[iIndex].Value);
             }

        }

        public static List<XmlNode> TraverseXml(XmlNodeList nodeList, int counter = 1)
        {
            List<XmlNode> matchNode = new List<XmlNode>();

            foreach (XmlNode node1 in nodeList)
            {
                if (node1.Attributes != null && node1.Attributes["match"] != null)
                {

                    matchNode.Add(node1.Attributes["match"]);

                }
                TraverseXml(node1.ChildNodes, counter);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
            return matchNode;
        }
```

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xd:xmldiff version="1.0" srcDocHash="11928043053884448382" options="IgnoreChildOrder IgnoreNamespaces IgnoreWhitespace IgnoreXmlDecl " fragments="no" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xmltools/2002/xmldiff">
    <xd:node match="2">
        <xd:node match="2">
            <xd:node match="19">
                <xd:node match="2">
                    <xd:add>Y</xd:add>
                </xd:node>
            </xd:node>
            <xd:add match="/2/2/11" opid="2" />
            <xd:change match="18" name="OWNINGSITE">
                <xd:node match="2">
                    <xd:remove match="1" />
                </xd:node>
            </xd:change>
            <xd:add match="/2/2/2-9" opid="1" />
            <xd:change match="17" name="STATUS">
                <xd:node match="2">
                    <xd:remove match="1" />
                </xd:node>
            </xd:change>
            <xd:remove match="14-16" />
            <xd:remove match="13" subtree="no">
                <xd:remove match="1-2" />
            </xd:remove>
            <xd:remove match="11" opid="2" />
            <xd:remove match="10" />
            <xd:remove match="2-9" opid="1" />
            <xd:remove match="1" />
        </xd:node>
        <xd:node match="5">
            <xd:node match="3">
                <xd:node match="11">
                    <xd:change match="1">0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1</xd:change>
                </xd:node>
            </xd:node>
        </xd:node>
    </xd:node>
    <xd:descriptor opid="1" type="move" />
    <xd:descriptor opid="2" type="move" />
</xd:xmldiff>
```

I am trying to display the values of returnedmatchNode. But its not displaying any value. I am unable to figure out the mistake in my code.

Comment: run your program in Visual Studio Debugger, set breakpoints, step through the code, inspect variables and see where it fails

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [mcve], so that people can actually reproduce your problem on their own PCs.

Comment: Have you verified that `returnedmatchNode` contains one or more values after the call to `TraverseXml`?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just waiting for you to press enter **once for every node** to get past all of those read lines? or is the XML really tiny

Comment: I did  check returnedmatchNode value. It not giving any value

Comment: @JamesBarrass no , its not waiting to press enter

Comment: Can you include a small sample of the xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the recursive call to

```
matchNode.AddRange(TraverseXml(node1.ChildNodes, counter));
```

otherwise you're not including the results of the recursion.

And for the sake the sanity for anyone running your code please move the `ReadLine()` to the end of `Main`

Answer (score 0):

You are always instantiating a new `List<XmlNode>` without adding the new results to it:

```
// this gets called in each round of your recursion
List<XmlNode> matchNode = new List<XmlNode>();
```

And in your method you're only adding the immediate childnodes to that list. You need to "carry" your intermediate results with you to the next recursion.

Just replace

```
TraverseXml(node1.ChildNodes, counter);
```

with

```
matchNode.AddRange(TraverseXml(node1.ChildNodes, counter));
```

Comment: It is, I ran it that way. What is not working exactly? I literally only added `matchNode.AddRange(...)` to your code and it worked.

Comment: you are keeping "List<XmlNode> matchNode = new List<XmlNode>();" as it is?

Comment: Yes, everything else stays the same. Except for what I explicitly changed.

Comment: hey thanks. I just needed to remove console.ReadLine(); from TraverseXml function.

Comment: Well the `Console.ReadLine` would not keep this from working, it's just tedious. Next time it would be helpful if instead of "it's not working" you could tell us exactly what the apparent error is.

Comment: actually there was no specific error as such. nothing was getting displayed